# Custom iterator using generic types

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to build a extension of ArrayList and build a custom Iterator for it, all in generic types, and I'm getting errors before compilation which I do not understand.

```
public class GenerateurBiGramme <T> extends ArrayList <T> {
    public Iterator<Pair<T,T>> iterator(int delta){
        return new BiGramme<>(delta);
    }
    public class BiGramme <T> implements Iterator<Pair<T, T>>{
        int premier = 0;
        int dernier = 1;
        int delta;
        public Pair<T, T> next() {
            Pair<T,T> temp = new Pair<T,T>(get(this.debut),get(this.dernier));
            return temp;
        }
```

My IDE is telling me that "Pair(T,T) in Pair cannot be applied to (T,T).

I don't understand what it means by that.

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: 
here is my "Pair" class:

```
public class Pair<T, U> {
    public T premiere;
    public U deuxieme;

    public Pair( T premiere, U deuxieme ) {
        this.premiere = premiere;
        this.deuxieme = deuxieme;
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm going to feed a table into the generator, and I intend to use "premier" and "dernier" to create pairs at a set distance from one another...

Comment: Is that `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair` or some other `Pair` class?  If it's your own class, can you show us the code please?

Comment: Could you post your whole class? There's so much to guess about `BiGramme, this.debut, this.dernier`...

Comment: I edited the post with the requested information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that in your declaration `public class BiGramme <T>`, the `T` hides the `T` that you declared in `public class GenerateurBiGramme <T>`.  You now have two different type parameters to `GenerateurBiGramme.BiGramme`, but unfortunately, they're both called `T`.

You don't need the `T` in the declaration of `BiGramme`, because it's an inner class, so it already has access to the type parameters of the outer class, `GenerateurBiGramme`.  Just change the declaration to `public class BiGramme`, without the `T`.  Also remove the `<>` from the line `return new BiGramme(delta);`.  This worked for me.